# Get simple list of all disks

Tags: linux, hard-disk, disk

How to get a list of all disks, like this?

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## ls (shows individual partitions though)

```
# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1
```

## ls (just disks, ignore partitions)

```
# ls /dev/sd*[a-z]
/dev/sda
```

## fdisk

```
# fdisk -l 2>/dev/null |awk '/^Disk \//{print substr($2,0,length($2)-1)}'
/dev/xvda
```

Comment: simple and easy `ls /dev/sd[a-z]` :)

Comment: @clarkk That wont work, once you pass "z" blockdevices; it then continues with /dev/sdaa

Answer (score 12):

You can use `df` to list all mounted partitions, the command will output something like

```
$ df
/dev/sda1      230467740  37314652 181422912  18% /
udev               10240         0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs            5599420         0   5599420   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      961303548 130106540 782342500  15% /media/Data
..
```

If you want to list only your mounted disks, you can filter the output with grep, for example

```
$ df | grep '^/dev'
/dev/sda1      230467740  37314752 181422812  18% /
/dev/sdb1      961303548 130106540 782342500  15% /media/Data
```

which matches lines starting with `/dev`, or, if you want only the names

```
df | grep -o '^/dev[^ ]*' 
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb1
```

which will match strings starting with `/dev` up to the first white space character, and output only the match (option `-o, --only-matching`),

**Edit**

The above will list all partitions, if you need to list the disks, use `lsblk` instead, with the following options (pattern matching as above)

```
$ lsblk -dp | grep -o '^/dev[^ ]*'
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
```

- `-d` lists only the device, without partitions
- `-p` outputs the whole path

**Edit 2**

As pointed out [below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360582/get-simple-list-of-all-disks#comment638757_360588), `lsblk -dpno name` will give the same result, no need for `grep`.

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti, edited my answer. I should definitely go through all options when skimming over man pages.